# Format image size in card regardless of the image's resolution

Tags: html, css

In angular I'm dynamically generating cards using `*ngFor` and want the images at the top of those cards to be the same size since otherwise it's causing the cards to be of unequal height. I want to replicate what ebay is doing but using cards instead.

I know that `object-fit: cover` can be used in this situation but the image will be 'zoomed in'

Mine:

```
  <!-- making the entire card clickable -->
  <a class="card h-100" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
     href="{{product.viewItemURL}}" style="width: inherit">

    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{product.pictureURLSuperSize}}">

    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 style="font-size: 1.1rem; margin-bottom: 0.5rem">{{product.title}}</h5>
      <div>

        <div style="float: right;font-size: 0.9rem; color: gray">{{product.condition.conditionDisplayName}}</div>
        <strong style="color: black">
          {{product.sellingStatus.currentPrice.__value__ |
          currency:product.sellingStatus.currentPrice.currencyId}}</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer" style="color: black; font-size: 0.9rem">
      <small class="text-muted">Time left: {{parseISO8601Duration(product.sellingStatus.timeLeft)}}</small>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Ebay:

```
<div class="s-item__image-wrapper">
  <div class="s-item__image-helper"></div>
  <img class="s-item__image-img" alt="..." src="...">
</div>

.s-item__image-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.s-item__image-helper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.s-item__image-img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

src: https://www.ebay.com/str/SAMCOMPUTERS/?listingOnly=1&_sop=1&rt=nc

This is what it currently looks like: 
[image: actual]

And this is what's expected:
[image: actual]

Answer (score 0):

Came across this which is the closest I've come across to a viable solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47479598/3841040

Using `padding-top: 56.25%` seems to look the best, although not perfect